If place a unique id upon a visitor then I store it into DB am I compliant with eu Requlation?
Into my php application I want to store this info:

slug
OS
Browser
Visitor Id

These will be a single table in my db counting hits for each vising of a given slug.
In my application I will NOT perform login but I will provide a visitor id via a session cookie and will be a random number. Each visit to slug may cause redirect to an external url.
The puproce is to make a url shortener but also count unique hits upon visiting a slug. But because I use Session cookies that are not nessesary for a url shortener, I am afraid I may violate the EU regulation regarding cookies also I may violate GDPR as well.
In the table mentioned above, the slug is the path of the url of my webapp.
So just by giving a unique id via session is a violation of EU regulations?

In the absence of consent, yes. GDPR does not differentiate between a session cookie and persistent data with a longer timespan. Even though there are multiple other tokens (IP address, TLS session identifier, TCP connection....) which have the same effective impact which are not expected to require consent or be disclosed, good luck with that defence in court.
But, assuming that the session cookie is an essential part of the service, you only need to inform the user of the cookie, not ask for consent before deploying it.
